# Is it safe or even code to place a furnace on top of a main water line?

Tags: water, furnace, foundation

This is a new build. Builders have allowed this but I anticipate if I ever have a problem it will be a complete disaster.
The furnace is sitting on top of the main water line coming out of the cement foundation.
Any advice would be appreciated [image]

Comment: Would not be on my list of top places to put the furnace, but main water lines do seem to last longer than furnaces usually.  New builds do have inspections of heating and plumbing, plus everything else.  Would imagine they would have fix the floor first though.

Comment: My question here would be...what detail of the hole (evidently bashed) in the concrete for the water line were they trying to hide by dropping the furnace on top of it? It appears to be a black poly waterline, so I'd expect it to outlast several furnaces and you. But that's some crappy standard of work with shards of concrete everywhere, which makes the choice of furnace (or waterline) location suspect. New builds have plans, plans show where services are to be located, it's not at all normal or acceptable practice to design the furnace to be on the water-line, so what in heck is going on?

Comment: Or: where do the plans show these things should be located?

Comment: The floor itself would seem to be of a concern in case of flooding from a high water table.  That section would probably be weakest to prevent water from coming up.

Comment: You say "Builders have allowed this", do you mean the actual construction companies involved or the building inspector? I can't imagine that the building inspector would overlook this unless he's somebody's brother-in-law... If this has passed inspection I'd email a picture of this to the building commissioner, especially if your town/city is big enough to have more than one employee. (Our little burg has only one, so that wouldn't help us in a situation like this.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to code. Utilities aren't my forte. To me that's superseded by more practical problems I'd want resolved before I'd be paying that builder another dime anyway. Here are my thoughts:

- This is just crappy planning. It would have me looking very closely at all other aspects of the build for shortcuts and poor foresight.
- Was there a clear utility layout in the contractual drawings? If so, what changed to result in this cluster****, or why wasn't the plan followed?
- Why would a builder worth their reputation leave you with this mess? Did they tell you with a straight face that it's all fine?
- Is there enough space around the furnace and all other equipment to do repairs and maintenance? Where is the air filter port? Does that condensate line run across an awkward area?

To my mind there's only one acceptable outcome here. It involves several key things, along with a general improvement in concern for quality:

- Furnace temporarily removed.
- Water line returned to vertical along the wall, with more slab cut out as needed.
- Slab repaired to professional quality finish.
- Water line run along the wall around the furnace with hard copper or plastic with elbows and anchored well to a better terminal location.
- Room thoroughly cleaned of all dust and debris.
- Furnace reinstalled.

I don't care if this is the cheapest house in a cookie-cutter subdivision. It's not at all acceptable, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree that poly will be shredded over time and then when it fails it will be on your dime, water hammer on that poly with all the sharp shards and metal base of the furnace this is slip-shod construction at its peak.

Comment: Make a lot of noise at the building enforcement place and the contractor.